# Python Arduino serial save to file

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

sorry for my english.
My Arduino serial give 3 values like this, at 300 Hz:

```html
-346 54 -191
-299 12 -123
-497 -214 77
-407 -55 -19
45 129 46
297 123 -197
393 71 -331
544 115 -273
515 -355 -89
510 -183 -47
```

Whit this python code I read and write correctly serial to file but after the while cycle do not terminate, and the shell remain open, and do not print stop:

```html
...
ard=serial.Serial(portname,baudrate)
print"start"

while True:
    x = ard.readline()
    #print x
    a=open(filename,'ab')
    a.write(x)
    a.close
    
print "stop"
...
```

I a biginner programmer, can you tell me a solution, to write serial to file and go forward.
Tanks

Comment: You have to break the loop when there is no more data

Answer (score 0):

You're never breaking from the while loop. You should:

1. Add a timeout to the serial reader
2. When there are no bytes received, break the loop

Taking your code as a base, try something like this:

```html
...
ard=serial.Serial(addr,baud)
ard.timeout = 1 # in seconds
print"start"

while True:
    x = ard.readline()
    if len(x) == 0:
        break
    a=open(fname,'ab')
    a.write(x)
    a.close
    
print "stop"
...
```

Comment: @lore.trango great! Make sure to vote up/accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works!
I have use ard.timeout and if condition (just if condition alone do not work).

An other question, 
My arduino serial start and terminate like this:

```html
Start
-663 -175 76
361 47 157
425 -229 -174
531 -283 -288
518 -40 -28
538 -228 206
581 188 174
445 5 176
end
```

It's possible to start write file after "Start" string and terminate before "end" string?
I have tried something like this but do not work:

```html
while True:
    x = ard.readline()
    if x=="end":
        break
    #print x
    a=open(fname,'ab')
    a.write(x)
    a.close
```

> Blockquote

```
enter code here
```